# Are CPU benchmarks of desktop versus laptop CPU indicative or real life performance?

Tags: cpu, benchmarking

According to benchmarks, it seems like the i5-8250u is about the same as an i5-7400.

i5-7400  passmark = 7415
https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-7400+%40+3.00GHz

i5-8259u passmark = 7577
https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-8250U+%40+1.60GHz

Now let's say the desktop with i5-7400 and laptop with i5-8250u have the same amount of RAM, both have SSD, the laptop would be plugged in the wall at full power.

Would both these machine perform the same or would the desktop be a lot faster because of better cooling and no throttling?

I would rather have a Laptop than desktop for mobility, but I fear laptop might be sluggish...even if it has good specs..;( I heard stories of throttling and so on...

This is for work and productivity, no games, no entertainment. Office apps, Adobe and occasional number crunching, laptop plugged in at all time. (only go out occasionally for coffee and set performance to low)

Comment: A benchmark is a benchmark.  I would expect a 7th generation Core processors to be slightly slower/weaker then an 8th generation Core processors.  The tasks you want to perform would benefit from more memory which is something you won’t have on a laptop.  Adobe is a GPU and memory hog, more computational power you throw at it, the better the performance.  You really shouldn’t compare desktop and laptop cpus to one another especially if you compare different generations of processors

Comment: If (when) parts on the laptop break down it would be a lot harder to replace them, compared to a desktop. But even on a desktop you could end up needing a whole new motherboard and possibly CPU since the popular sockets seem to change yearly (almost seasonally), though all the other parts should still be reusable. Probably depends on how cheap you can get them in the first place.